# Why do many WPF-classes store boolean values as enum-flags?

Tags: c#, wpf, coding-style, boolean, enum-flags

If you reflect over the WPF `System.Windows.Controls.Control` class you can see:

```
public class Control : FrameworkElement
{ 
    internal ControlBoolFlags _controlBoolField;
    // [...]
    internal bool ReadControlFlag(ControlBoolFlags reqFlag);
    internal void WriteControlFlag(ControlBoolFlags reqFlag, bool set); 
    // I think it's clear what they do
    // [...]
    internal enum ControlBoolFlags : ushort
    {
        CommandDisabled = 8,
        ContainsSelection = 128,
        ContentIsItem = 16,
        ContentIsNotLogical = 1,
        HeaderIsItem = 32,
        HeaderIsNotLogical = 4,
        IsSpaceKeyDown = 2,
        ScrollHostValid = 64,
        VisualStateChangeSuspended = 256
    }
}
```

So I just want to know why MS chose this way to store the boolean values instead of using a `bool` field for every flag.
Is it just their style of coding oder did they just want to save space for every field?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's several reason. A couple include:

- It's a huge space-saver.  1 short representing many (9 in this example) possiblities. That's the size of single ushort rather than many bools
- You can pass all those values to a method in a single parameter rather than having many parameters and a bunch of overloaded methods.